# how to change event on legend click in amcharts 5?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

the same problem solve is here https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/activate-deactivate-a-pie-slice-on-legend-click-instead-of-toggling/ , I need to have the same effect but it doesnt work in version 5

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was a really trivial issue, but it took a while to figure this out so here you go:
All you need to do is set the legend data AFTER your listener.
As commented in the demo below

`It's is important to set legend data after all the events are set on template, otherwise events won't be copied`

Demo: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/highlighting-line-chart-series-on-legend-hover/

Example

```
legend.itemContiners.template.events.on("click", function(ev) {
    // Do whatever you want when clicked on Legend
}

legend.data.setAll(chart.series.values)
```